# How do you list keywords as conditions more effectively?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a script that cleans up and saves bibtex entries into my library-file. I need the script to read a .bib file and then write its content into the library file but excluding certain fields/lines. I've tried things like putting every field I want to exclude into

```
exclusions = ["exclusion1","exclusion2","exclusion3",..."exclusionN"]
```

and then looping over it like so

```
if [ex for ex in exclusion not in line]:
   ...code...
```

But that didnt work so eventually I settled with this

```
...
with open("newbib.bib", "a") as f1:
    for line in lines:
         if "abstract" not in line and "keywords" not in line and "issn" not in line and "ISSN" not in line and "url" not in line and "URL" not in line and "eprint" not in line and "publisher" not in line and "address" not in line and "number" not in line and "day" not in line and "month" not in line and "pages" not in line:
                            f1.writelines(line)
...
```

The if statement that I'm showing below does the trick but its a damn bad way to do it, right?
Also, it would be nice to not have to add capitalization for each field.

Comment: Are you looking for the ``any`` or ``all`` builtin, perhaps? As in ``if all(ex for ex in exclusion not in line):``

Comment: Using any or all gives me the error that exclusions needs to be a string and not a list, which is pretty confusion tbh

Comment: Sorry, I copy/pasted your incorrect syntax. It should read ``if all(ex not in line for ex in exclusion):``

Comment: That did the trick, molto bene, grazie

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: No need to add "solved" to the title; accepting an answer is enough to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `any` or `all` builtin to check whether any or all elements of an iterable apply. In your case, that means iterating through all exclusions and checking whether they are not in the line:

```
if all(ex not in line for ex in exclusion):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
ex_list = [ex for ex in exclusions if x != "exclusion1" and x != "exclusion2"]
```

(or)

keep exlusions to be skipped in a list if your condition is longer
e.g

```
skip_list = []
ex_list = [ex for ex in exclusions if ex not in skip_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to test for all of the exclusions at once:

```py
>>> exclusions = ["exclusion1", "exclusion2", "exclusion3"]
>>> import re
>>> exclude = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, exclusions))).search
>>> not exclude('hello world')
True
>>> not exclude('exclusion2 world')
False
```

So you can write the `if` statement like:

```py
if not exclude(line):
    ...
```

Comment: This does look neat but it throws me a type error that re.Pattern is not callable. I tried adding `exclude = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape(pattern), exclusions)))` and `exclude(line,exclusions)` but nope

Comment: You're missing the `.search` at the end of that line.