# simplify multiple or statements in if else

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, generator

I have this code to search for text in a list and also parts of the text

```
  if issi in self.issi_list \
     or issi[:2] in self.issi_list \
     or issi[:3] in self.issi_list \
     or issi[:4] in self.issi_list \
     or issi[:5] in self.issi_list \
     or issi[:6] in self.issi_list:
```

I hoped to use a generator to replace them like

```
if issi in self.issi_list or [issi[:x] in self.issi_list for x in range(2, 6)]:
```

But it does not seem to work. Am I completely on the wrong track?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you list keywords as conditions more effectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191703/how-do-you-list-keywords-as-conditions-more-effectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely:

```
if issi in self.issi_list or any([issi[:x] in self.issi_list for x in range(2, 7)]):
```

1. You generated a list of the individual test results, but didn't combine them
2. `range` goes up to *but doesn't include* the second argument

Comment: Thanks that was perfect. And I see what I was doing wrong.